# Am I choosing the right technologies for my new project?

Tags: c++, gui, qt

I'm in the process of designing a new project and have some technology descisions to make.

The project has the following requirements:

- Will be written in C++
- Will have a complex and highly dynamic GUI
- must run on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X
- must be extensible with user/community defined plugins
- plugins must be capable to extend the UI (e.g. custom windows/dialogs)
- plugins must be platform independent (no pre-compiled libraries)

---

I have already made some considerations about what technologies I want to use:

- CMake as build system
- GUI implemented with QT
- Plugins written in python and run with an integrated python interpreter

---

Will these technologies fulfill my requirements?

Am I missing something?

Should I use something else?

Also I'm uncertain if I should use QT Quick/QML or QT widgets.

Comment: Run on many o/s - fine, but which o/s will you develop on? Do you want to use only cost-free, or do you have a budget?

Comment: @Mawg: development will be mostly on Linux. The project will be FOSS and only cost-free.

Comment: So, any recommendations that we make must be FOSS?